# Kodo on JBoss 7

Tags: java, java-8, jboss7.x, kodo

We are looking to run replace Oracle Kodo 4 persistence (JPA) framework as it does not build with JDK 1.8 and JBoss EAP 7 throwing error in Maven build.

Is there any official document supporting Kodo has been deprecated and would not work with JBoss EAP 7? I managed to only get this [reference link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs324/j2ee_tutorial_jca_installation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KODO comes with enhancement mechanism (recompiles DTO with persistence functions and enhancement) which damages the byte-code validation. So for JBoss EAP 7 working on JDK 1.8 we need to set the –noverify for the JAVA_OPTS. This will disable the bytecode validation for the class files being loaded, and KODO can run on JBoss EAP 7 with JDK 1.8.